# Ajax HTTP request from cordova win-10

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cordova, windows-10-universal

we've got an issue while trying to reach our back-end server from a Windows-10 cordova app with XHR (AngularJS $http call).
The back-end server is available (test with a RESTclient plugin in a browser).
The application is installed on a windows-10 desktop pc with VisualStudio 2015 enables (to view logs).

Here's the error in log (sorry in french):

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Erreur réseau 0x2efd, Impossible d’effectuer l’opération à cause de l’erreur suivante 00002efd.
```

We added the following meta-tag in our index.html file (we also tried the wildcard *):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: http://10.148.118.68/* gap: http://10.148.118.68/* 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And here's the config.xml settings:

```
<access origin="*" /> 
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

For information, we've built and deployed successfully the application on an Android Device and the app reached the back-end.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default project settings in config.xml created with cordova CLI doesn't include capabilities for PrivateNetwork XHR.
We have to add it "manually":

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 0):

> we've got an issue while trying to reach our back-end server from a Windows-10 cordova app with XHR (AngularJS $http call).

This is by design as extensions don’t support loopback. Please refer to [Edge Extension cannot request to localnets](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8438041/).

Comment: do you mean it's not possible "by design" to call any private IP addresses (10.x.x.x)?

Comment: It's not possible using extensions Ajax(like jquery or angular) to call local IP Address. You can try using [HttpXMLRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: what do you mean by local IP address? our win10 application calls our back-end hosted on a remote ip address. shouldn't we add the capability for PrivateNetworks in windows10 appxmanifest instead?

Comment: OK, private IP address, apologize for that, privateNetwork capability is also necessary, have you tried using XMLHttpRequest instead?